# C# How to Reference a File From Solution Explorer > Resources

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

How can I reference a file that is in my program's Resources. Let's say I have added foo.csv, how can I get the "path" to the file. I have tried:

```
Properties.Resources.foo.csv

App.Workbooks.Open(Properties.Resources.foo.csv);
```

I have installed it in Properties and set the the Build Action to "Embedded Resource".

EDIT:

I can open the file as a .csv in my program when calling the file from my C drive, I just cant get the embedded resource to be recognized and loaded.

Comment: Drop the ".csv"

Comment: But if you are trying to get Excel to open that, you would have to export your contents into a file that Excel can open.

Comment: I did, the build error says "Properties.Resources Does Not Contain A Definition for 'foo"

Comment: In addition to what @LarsTech has said, you can find/change the name of your resource file by going to Project `Properties > Resources > Files`. You can rename the resource there. For example, you could add a file named "foo.csv" and have its name in the Resources = "bar", therefore, you can access it using `Properties.Resources.bar` _(although the filename is still "foo.csv" in the Resources folder)_.

Comment: You need to stop attempting to make this work, Excel requires a file on disk and cannot use an embedded resource.

Comment: How can I attach it in the properties folder and link to it as an Excel file and deploy it in the click once application?

Comment: @CRIMSON501, LarsTech already told you how in his second comment.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed check my edit!

Comment: I already did! Have you double-checked the resource name yet? Once you do that and you're able to call `Properties.Resources.SomeName`, that's the "recognize" part. This will return a byte array which you can export to a temporary location and then "load" it the same way you load the file in your C drive.

Comment: I have, and the file is recognized now! I am not familiar with this method. How can I get the file and export it to a temp folder?

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Properties.Resources.SomeName);`

Answer (score 1):

What I have ended up doing is putting the foo.csv file in C:\Program Files\My-Program\Resources\ and adding error handling if the file does not exist. It will connect to my server and download the file. Thank you for all your help!